# Java error when converting String in ArrayList to int

Tags: java, string, arraylist, casting, int

I am *very* new at Java.  I am trying to write a lottery simulator.  I have the following code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter six whole numbers between 1 and 49 in a comma-separated list: ");
String userNumbersString = input.nextLine();
String[] userNumbersArray = userNumbersString.replaceAll("\\s+","").split(",");
ArrayList userNumbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(userNumbersArray));
boolean validNumbers = true;
for(int v = 0; v <= 6; v++){
    if((int)userNumbers.get(v) > 49){
        validNumbers = false;
            v = 7;
        }else{
            v++;
        }
    }
if(validNumbers == false){
    String[] str = new String[0];
    main(str);
}
```

It compiles properly.  However, when I input a series of numbers, I get this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

I am very confused about why this string can't be cast to an integer.

Sorry if this is a long-winded question, but I would hugely appreciate any help.

I have just realised that the OutOfBounds exception was due to a stupid maths mistake on my part; v was starting at 0; there were five values in the array, but I gave the for loop the condition <= 6.  Sorry about that.

Thank you everybody for all your help.  Together, you have resolved my question.

Comment: Don't include massages for one person in question itself. Leave it as comment under this person answer.

Comment: @Pshemo OK; sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms

`int` is a primitive type for representing a 32-bit integer number.
`String` is a reference type wrapped arround an array of `char`s to represent a sequence of characters.

You cannot just change the type from `int` to `String` and make the character sequence in the string magically becomes a number.

Think about how you would implement this conversion. You would look at each character, make sure it is a valid digit etc.

Change:

```
if((int)userNumbers.get(v) > 49)
```

To:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(userNumbers.get(v)) > 49)
```

Further, when creating Generic type containers like `ArrayList` make sure you also declare what type of objects they store for type safety reasons.

Change:

```
ArrayList userNumbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(userNumbersArray));
```

To:

```
ArrayList<String> userNumbers = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(userNumbersArray));
```

This way you calling `userNumber.get()` will return a `String`.
If you don't put this it will return an `Object` so you would actually call `Integer.parseInt(Object)` which is invalid. You would get a pretty self-explanatory error looking like this:

> The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

**EDIT:**

For your `IndexOutOfBounds` error, you are trying to access more elements than you have. Basically, you want to have 6 values but your `for` loop says `from 0 until 6 (included)`. That is a total of 7 elements: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

You can fix this by changing the `<= 6` to `< 6` in your loop but the best way to fix it so it will work no matter how many elements you have is to use the `size()` property of `ArrayList`:

Change:

```
for(int v = 0; v <= 6; v++)
```

To:

```
for(int v = 0; v < userNumbers.size(); v++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but, when I do this, I get a compilation error.  I will update my original question with the error as it is quite long.

Comment: Why `valueOf` instead of `parseInt`? In this case, there is no reason to use an `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 you are correct, although it still works, parseInt is a better choice. Updated my answer

Comment: @user3315726 `valueOf` expects String as argument, while `get` returns `Object` because you didn't specified what type of elements should `ArrayList` store. To do this you would have to use generic types (also prefer interfaces over implementation) so change `ArrayList userNumbers = new ArrayList(...` to `List<String> userNumbers = new ArrayList<String>(...`.

Comment: @Pshemo haha I literally just added that part, telepathy wow :) thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @user3315726 about "*why this string can't be cast to an integer*" it is because Java is strong typed language.

Comment: I now understand that; however, what I don't get is why I am getting an outofbounds exception

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use generics for `ArrayList`. Please replace

```
ArrayList userNumbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(userNumbersArray));
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> userNumbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(userNumbersArray));
```

However, this is not your problem. The misconception here is that casting will infer what type of conversion you need; **it won't**. Replace `(int)userNumbers.get(v)` with `Integer.parseInt(userNumbers.get(v))` to parse the `int` from a `String`.

Comment: I have now used generics and it will compile with parseInt, but I get an error after inputting the comma-separated number string: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 6, size: 6 (in java.util.ArrayList)

Answer (score 0):

Type casting is not meant to parse an Integervalue from an String.

You should use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) for that.

`if(Integer.parseInt(userNumbers.get(v)) > 49`

should solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because of the <= 6 in your for loop.

Secondly, you should use the Integer.parseInt(String intStr) method to turn each number into its int equivalent.

Here is a stripped down version that I think works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String testInputOne = "14,22,18,2,5,11";

    boolean allNumbersAreValid = true;

    String[] userNumbersStrArray = testInputOne.split(",");

    for (String numberStr: userNumbersStrArray)
    {
        Integer number = Integer.parseInt(numberStr.trim());

        if (number > 49)
        {
            allNumbersAreValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Testing " + testInputOne + ": " + (allNumbersAreValid?"All valid!":"At least one invalid"));
}
```

If you want to further guard against bad input such as someone entering an alpha character, you could wrap the Integer.parseInt call in a try catch block and catch the NumberFormatException and output a suitable error message.

I'm frankly a little scared as to what the recursive call to main is supposed to do?  :)